# Getting a line from JTextArea when clicking on it

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, mouseevent, jtextarea

This is only for learning purposes.

I have two JTextArea-s: messagearea and chatarea. There is a random text in messagearea, as usual, lines are separated with \n. When clicking on a line, i would like to append that line to chatarea. Here is my code:

```
messagearea.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
    {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me)
        {
            if (!messagearea.getText().trim().equals("")) {
                int position = messagearea.viewToModel(messagearea.getMousePosition());
                String[] text = messagearea.getText().split("\n");
                int[] charNum = new int[text.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
                    charNum[i] = text[i].length() + 1;
                }
                int sum = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < charNum.length; i++) {
                    sum += charNum[i];
                    if (sum >= position) {
                        chatarea.append(text[i] + "\n");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

I would like to know, if there was an easier way to do this.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to know, if there was an easier way to do this.

It is not a very efficient solution since you are parsing the entire Document every time which will get worse as the amount of text in the text area increases.

Use text area methods that take advantage of the Document structure. Something like:

```
int line = textArea.getLineOfOffset( textArea.getCaretPosition() );
int start = textArea.getLineStartOffset( line );
int end = textArea.getLineEndOffset( line );
String text = textArea.getDocument().getText(start, end - start);
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly i wanted to know!:)

Comment: Great answer... but the last line should be 'String text=...' not 'int text=...'

Comment: @JMax, `but the last line should be...` - fixed.